# How to avoid remounting component when URI update is needed (e.g. filter buttons)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Using `react-router v3` & `redux` I basically have a routes setup similar to the following:

```
<Route name="app" path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Catalogue} />
  <Route name="brand" path="/brand/(:brand)" component={Catalogue} />
</Route>
```

My Catalogue makes an async request to fetch **all** my products and then stores them in state. Additionally my *Catalogue* component has multiple *brand* buttons using `Link` from `react-router`, and each link goes to something like:

- */brand/brandA*
- */brand/brandB*
- */brand/brandC*

When a user clicks a brand filter button the Catalogue has logic that filters and only shows products belonging to brandX as part of the url params.

In Catalogue component I have something like the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.params.brand) {
    // this is a redux action dispatch
    this.props.setBrandFilter(this.props.params.brand);
  }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**: 
My issue right now is that every time a user clicks a brand filter link on my Catalogue component the router catches it (good thing.), my Catalogue component always get remounted (bad thing.) and again fetches *ALL* my products (horrible thing!). After fetching all products then it filters the list by brand (if on a brand specific route).

Basically I need a way to update the URL in address bar to reflect the brand filter change (i.e user navigated to /brand/brandA) for analytics purposes, but I want to avoid:

- re-mounting the **same** catalogue component
- re-fetching **all** the products again

This is a performance killer! Does anyone know how to do something like this? Any tips or advice would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have them as separate components on separate routes, then they're going to be re-mounted. You're explicitly telling it to do so. There's a few things you could do to avoid this.

- Don't trigger all your data fetches by component mount. This is okay on small-scale, trivial projects, but it breaks down pretty fast. The [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) architecture is designed specifically for this. Do your fetches upfront (on application load), and load those products into a store.
- If your routing table is as simple as that, one of the big things react-router v4 makes easier is nesting routes that render partial content for a page. React is all about dealing with rendering components, not pages, so it's about time our router got away from the whole 'one URL for one complete webpage'. The [react router sidebar](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar) example is a great reference to start with. You can apply this example to more than just headers, sidebars, and footers. You could apply it in your case so that the parent `<Catalog>` never needs to re-mount.

  `<Route name="app" path="/" component={App}>
    <Catalog>
      <Route name="brand" path="/brand/(:brand)" component={BrandList} />
    </Catalog>
  </Route>`

Comment: Same component, but is attached on two different routes - the IndexRoute: `/` and the brand filter route `/brand/(:brand)`. It only gets remounted when  switching between the IndexRoute and a brand filter route back and forth. Would like to avoid this since it's the SAME component - but need the URL updated. Will take a look at your first suggestion which should help w/ re-fetching, but won't fix the remounting issue. Thanks.

Comment: It fixes your remounting issue. You can't go around changing the parents, but if you're only changing the contents of a component you can do this with routes. In their sidebar example, it' not continually unmounting and remounting the sidebard either. However you choose to structure your routes, if you keep the parent/child relationship where the list of brands can be included as `this.props.children` inside your `<Catalog>`'s `render`, it'll work. That said, remounting is a fairly minor problem when you're not tying your remote fetches to the component mount.